# Classes of sheaves and the Riemann-Roch theorem (Grothendieck 1957)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I couldn't find this paper (preferably english translation) on the web, math.stackexchange, or mathoverflow.net; could someone please point me to the document to read? Thanks!

Comment: Usually referred to as Borel-Serre.

Comment: To be more explicit about the ref., it's  Borel, Serre,  *Le theoreme de Riemann-Roch, d'apres Grothendieck*. Google it, and you'll find the link.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, Grothendieck didn't publish these results. They appeared in

> Armand Borel and Jean-Pierre Serre, *Le théorème de Riemann-Roch*, Bulletin de la S. M. F., tome 86 (1958), p. 97-136 doi:[10.24033/bsmf.1500](https://doi.org/10.24033/bsmf.1500)

The paper is subtitled *(d'après des résultats inédits de A. GROTHENDIECK)*.

Comment: There are also handwritten notes by Grothendieck (on the Marseille archive webpage), but I find them hard to read. Apparently Grothendieck gave a course on RR at the College de France, but I am not sure if these notes were published.

Comment: @EinfacherSchreiberling I guess you mean the second item here: https://grothendieck.umontpellier.fr/archives-grothendieck/

Comment: "Classes de faisceaux et théorème de Riemann-Roch" is also included in Exposé 0 of SGA 6 (LNM 225).

Comment: http://library.msri.org/books/sga/sga/pdf/sga6.pdf (52MB!) Official Springer version is at https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0066284 & starts on page 20.